# Loading biggiest catalog on autocomplete component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, sat

I am working on a developer web application in vue, where vuetify was integrated.

It is required to load a sat catalog with about 50 thousand records, the problem is that when the data is loaded in the v-autocomplete the other fields of the form have an anomalous behavior, for example, when wanting to write in a text-field there is a delay of 1 to 3 seconds in seeing what was written reflected.

Adjunt sql query

**select
Cat_ProdServConsignmentNoteId, ProdServConsignmentNoteKey, Description
from Cat_ProdServConsignmentNote
where IsActive = 1 and IsDelete = 0**

[Table columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUI7O.png)

Comment: Several possible reasons. You should start by limiting the results of the query, that's the most important. Maybe all records meet the criteria because someone entered the joker (`*`, `?`, `%`, `[blankspace]`) where you must limit the records to avoid DoS. Please attach code to your question that makes the issue clear and reproducible.

Comment: You are not narrowing the dataset at all. In the worst case you are sending ~50 thousand records to the browser, 10-20 megabytes.